# Android Studio: Duplicate files copied in APK project.properties

Tags: android, gradle, google-api, android-gradle-plugin, google-translate

After adding the Google Translate API `compile 'com.google.cloud:google-cloud-translate:0.18.0-beta'` to my project, I have been getting a strange error

> Error:Execution failed for task ':ParseStarterProject:transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForDebug'.
>   com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.builder.packaging.DuplicateFileException: Duplicate files copied in APK project.properties
>       File1: .gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.google.cloud/google-cloud-translate/0.18.0-beta/9cac04f2bb48f76f352bf65d782506e4aa18406c/google-cloud-translate-0.18.0-beta.jar
>       File2: /.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.google.cloud/google-cloud-core/1.0.2/ff451b4b785369093bd91d277c22576fc9c1da3a/google-cloud-core-1.0.2.jar

There are other SO posts which mention "Duplicate files copied in APK META_INF", or "Duplicate files copied in APK LICENSE.txt", etc

However, I have not seen anyone else encounter the error "duplicate files copied in APK project.properties"

**Adding these to my gradle does not work**

```
packagingOptions {
  exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
  exclude 'META-INF/io.netty.versions.properties'
  exclude 'META-INF/INDEX.LIST'
  exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
  exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
  exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
  exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
}
```

Is there something else I can add to my gradle to fix this error? Or is there another way to fix this error by removing "FILE2" as shown in the error logs?

**GRADLE**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
 useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
 packagingOptions {
   // exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
   //exclude 'META-INF/io.netty.versions.properties'
   //exclude 'META-INF/INDEX.LIST'
 }

compileSdkVersion rootProject.ext.compileSdkVersion
buildToolsVersion rootProject.ext.buildToolsVersion
defaultConfig {
    multiDexEnabled true
    applicationId "com.package.name"
    minSdkVersion rootProject.ext.minSdkVersion
    targetSdkVersion rootProject.ext.targetSdkVersion
    versionCode 41
    versionName "2.1"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
lintOptions {
    disable 'MissingTranslation'
    disable 'ExtraTranslation'
}
dexOptions {
    javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:10.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:10.2.0'
    //noinspection GradleCompatible
    compile 'com.google.cloud:google-cloud-translate:0.18.0-beta'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.parse.bolts:bolts-tasks:1.3.0'
    compile 'com.parse:parse-android:1.13.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
    //noinspection GradleDynamicVersion
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:[4,5)'
    //noinspection GradleCompatible
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:10.2.0'
    // compile 'com.onesignal:OneSignal:3.4.3@aar'

  }


 }
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
 dependencies {
 compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.1'
  }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the google cloud core dependancy

While adding translate dependancy do this

```
compile ('com.google.cloud:google-cloud-translate:0.5.0') {
    exclude group: 'io.grpc', module: 'grpc-all'
    exclude group: 'com.google.protobuf', module: 'protobuf-java'
    exclude group: 'com.google.api-client', module: 'google-api-client-
    appengine'
}
```

Comment: Funny thing is that I never added a google cloud core dependancy.

Comment: Post the gradle file

Comment: posted gradle file

Answer (score 10):

in my case,

```
packagingOptions {
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
    exclude 'META-INF/io.netty.versions.properties'
    exclude 'META-INF/INDEX.LIST'
    exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
    exclude 'project.properties' <------------------------here
}
```